# Reading a file as a 2d char array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, java.util.scanner

How do you read in data from a text file that contains nothing but `char`s into a 2d array using only `java.io.File`, `Scanner`, and file not found exception?

Here is the method that I'm trying to make that will read in the file to the 2D array.

```
public AsciiArt(String filename, int nrRow, int nrCol){
    this.nrRow = nrRow;
    this.nrCol = nrCol;

    image = new char [nrRow][nrCol];

    try{
        input = new Scanner(filename);

        while(input.hasNext()){

        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're importing `java.io.*` (or specific classes that you need if that's what you want) to include the `FileNotFoundException` class. It was a bit hard to show how to fill the 2D array since you didn't specify how you want to parse the file exactly. But this implementation uses Scanner, File, and FileNotFoundException.

```
public AsciiArt(String filename, int nrRow, int nrCol){
    this.nrRow = nrRow;
    this.nrCol = nrCol;
    image = new char[nrRow][nrCol];

    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        while(input.hasNext()){
            String c = input.next();
            image[row][column] = c.charAt(0);

            column++;

            // handle when to go to next row
        }   

        input.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        // handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, that helped to jog my memory. I've been pouring over different code and sometimes I forgot.

Comment: Do you not increment `row`? Is it always 0?

Comment: You increment the row where the comment "// handle when to go to next row" is. I didn't show row being incremented because the OP didn't specify how big the lines are or how they are detecting the end of line. But the solution would be: if all the rows are the same length (i.e. all 7 columns wide), you'd increment the row every 7 columns. If the rows are different lengths (have variable columns), then you'd check if you're at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

A rough way of doing it would be:

```
    File inputFile = new File("path.to.file");
    char[][] image = new char[200][20];
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    int read = -1;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while ((read = in.read()) != -1 && x < image.length) {
        image[x][y] = (char) read;
        y++;
        if (y == image[x].length) {
            y = 0;
            x++;
        }
    }
    in.close();
```

However im sure there are other ways which would be much better and more efficient but you get the principle.